# Google Play console - Internal testing instead of the Latest release the old release is available for the internal testers

Tags: google-play

[image]

Google Play console - Internal testing instead of the Latest release the old release is available for the internal testers.

Answer (score 0):

It takes time for the status to move from "In review" to "Available...." where your release 12 would be available to internal testers and release 8 would change to something not live.

How long does it take? Who or what is doing the reviewing? Man, if you designed a system to be opaque and confusing you would have screwed up somewhere and done something accidentally more useful than what actually exists. Don't get me started.